# PHP preg_match doesn't match list separated with commas

Tags: php, regex

Here's my users list

```
james,john,mark,luke,

james,john,mark,luke,mary,david
```

I want to remove the repeated part and retain the remaining.

So here's my code

```
$old   = 'james,john,mark,luke,';
$users = 'james,john,mark,luke,mary,david';

// Replace , with |
$expr = rtrim(preg_replace('/\,/', '|', $old), '|');

$newstr = preg_replace("/$expr/i", '', $users);

echo $newstr;
```

Output

> ,,,,mary,david

I want

> mary,david,

Comment: Make life easier: Convert both strings into arrays with `explode()`, then use `array_diff()` to get the difference of the two arrays.

Comment: Unless this is a simplified test case to illustrate the issue, you should just use arrays. Even if your original data looks like that, implode()/explode() are trivial to use.

Comment: In general: in programming, you will want to do as little *string manipulation* as possible. It may be enticing and simple to grasp on its surface, but it's a quagmire of misery if that's all you do. `array_diff(array_filter(explode(',', $old)), array_filter(explode(',', $users)))` → much saner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A solution, based on your code using [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):**

```
$old = 'james,john,mark,luke,';
$users = 'james,john,mark,luke,mary,david';

$expr = rtrim(preg_replace('/\,/', '|', $old), '|');
$newstr = preg_replace("/$expr/i", '', $users);
echo trim($newstr, ',');
```

*Demo:* https://3v4l.org/W3XKe

**A better solution using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):**

```
$old = 'james,john,mark,luke,';
$users = 'james,john,mark,luke,mary,david';

$old_items = explode(',', $old);
$users_items = explode(',', $users);

echo implode(array_diff($users_items, $old_items), ',');
```

*Demo:* https://3v4l.org/tnt9F

Comment: Well that is just a coincidence now that the values he wants to keep are at the end of the string. If there would be other values between and behind them the output also could be: `,,,XY1,,,,XY2,,,`. And `ltrim()` wouldn't remove the middle commas nor the ones at the end

Comment: like @Rizier123 said, I want also remove the existing part of both sides and how can I do that?

Comment: see update and demos - now using `trim` not `ltrim`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it right now, but wouldn't it work simply like that?

```
$old   = 'james,john,mark,luke,';
$users = 'james,john,mark,luke,mary,david';
echo preg_replace("/$old/", "", $users); //should print "mary,david"
```